# What browser settings do you test with?

Tags: testing, web-applications, browser

Do you test your applications under multiple browser settings?  Do you use test tools that tell you why your site might be problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a couple of different machine images with IE6/IE7/IE8 FF2/FF3 Chrome, Opera & Safari for windows installed on them.

For developers, most have IE7 & Firefox installed. The [Firefox Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) Add-in is handy. As is [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), [Y-Slow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) & [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647).

We'll target most sites to 1024*768 and then test to see they look fine @

```
1280*1024
1280*768 
1920*1080
1920*1200
```

For simple UI Interaction, we've used [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) in the past for automated/macro testing

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has very useful [WebDeveloper add-on](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/). Lets you disable/enable various features of the browser on the fly. You can check how will your app work with cookies disabled or in 800x600 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Besides testing various resolutions I also test with different DPI I've found its common for offices to use 120dpi on their workstations which can break sites in IE especially.

Answer (score 1):

Color usage for the color blind: http://vischeck.com/

Answer (score 0):

I usually test pages with designs which are critical for browser-compatibility in browsershots. Try it yourself: [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/)